# Copy and paste range issue

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I'm coming up with an runtime error 9, subscript out of range, in my code and was wondering how I could fix it

**Original Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumn()

    Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range
    
    Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("E1")
    Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1")
    
    rgSource.Copy
    rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

The error appears on `Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("E1")`

So I thought that the issue was linked to sizing and I wrote the code below but the issue still persists

**New Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumn()

    Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range
    
    Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("E1")
    Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1")
    
    Set rgDestination = rgDestination.Resize(rgSource.Rows.Count, rgSource.Columns.Count)
    
    rgDestination.Value = rgSource.Value

End Sub
```

Do you know how I could rectify this issue?

These are the screenshots of my code

[image]

The sheet names

[image]

This is the error message (in French as I'm working on a french computer)

[image]

Comment: "Subscript Out of Range Error (Run Time: Error 9) occurs when you refer to an object or try to use a variable in a code that doesn't exist in the code". I.e. the sheet does not exist; it is probably called "Sheet1" without the whitespace? Also: try to avoid `copy/paste`. Use `.Value = .Value`, as you are doing in the second snippet.

Comment: Are you sure that the sheet names you are using are correct?  Take a long look at the names on the Tabs

Comment: The sheets are probably named `"Sheet1"` (without space) and not `"Sheet 1"`  (with space). Please verify! Remove the space in the code.

Comment: Hi, I'm a 100% sure that the sheet names are correct. I've even called the sheets "1" and "2" and I've also changed my code accordingly. I've tried several options ie not using option explicit. Do you know what could be causing this error? Thanks,

Comment: @BikatUprety The error in this line `Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("E1")`  can only be caused by a wrong worksheet name. Either the sheet does not exist in the workbook the code is written in or it has a wrong name. There is no other possibility for that error. Please make screenshots of the tab bar to show the names. The sheets need to be in the same workbook as the VBA code.

Comment: Okay will post screenshots in a question

Comment: Is there more than one workbook open in your Excel? Did you restart your computer (just in case)?

Comment: No, there were no other workbooks, however, I've solved the issue. I was putting this code in my Personal.xlsb in VB Editor and not under the workbook where I wanted to execute the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BikatUprety Well I don't recommend that because if this workbook is used by another computer it won't be able to run the macros. Or if you move on to a new computer and forget to coyp your personal.xlsb your code is lost too. Anyway if you put this same code into personal.xlsb then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("E1")` will refer to worksheets in personal.xlsb and not to your worksheet. Highly not recommended!